# PropTypes not required, but showing as required in VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I just recently added a jsconfig.json file to my javascript react project to get better imports, aliases etc. Everything is working right now and I even got some enhanced type safety. My problem is VSCode seems to be looking at the function parameters and not the PropTypes to check if a prop is required. What is the correct way of marking a parameter as optional in javascript? I cannot just tag a question mark on the end like in Typescript. The code compiles and runs fine, it us just VSCode complaining. I have ran VSCode without any extensions so I know its not an extension doing it.

The error is

```js
Property 'className' is missing in type '{ active: true; png: true; }' but required in type '{ [x: string]: any; active: any; className: any; png: any; width?: number; }'.
```

[image]

Here are my files, I have simplified the code

```json
// jsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@components/*": ["./common/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

```js
// BuildYourTeam.jsx

import React from 'react'

import CreditCard from '@components/CreditCard'

const BuildYourTeam = ({ className }) => {

  return (
    <div>
          <CreditCard active png />
    </div>
  )
}

export default BuildYourTeam
```

```js
// CreditCard.jsx

import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import creditCard from '@images/credit_card.png'
import styling from './creditCard.module.scss'

/**
 * Simple component for displaying credit card images
 */
const CreditCard = ({ active, className, png, width = 100, ...props }) => {
  const classes = classNames(className, 'inline-block', 'relative')
  let image

  // At smaller sizes the png looks better for active
  if (png && active) {
    image = (
      <img className={styling.active} src={creditCard} width={width} alt='Credit Card' {...props} />
    )
  } 

  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      {image}
      <div className={styling.background} />
    </div>
  )
}

CreditCard.propTypes = {
  active: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  png: PropTypes.bool,
  width: PropTypes.number,
}

export default CreditCard
```

Comment: Either declare an interface and mark the optional props with `?` at the end or do it with `defaultPropTypes` and set it to nulll

Comment: There is no way to get VScode to read it from the PropTypes? Also do interfaces work in javsacript? Never tried

Comment: I don't believe there is another way. Check my answer and see if that works

Comment: @TomelSafadi I go the error: `'interface' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.`

Comment: Make the file `.tsx`

Comment: Restricted to .jsx only in this project unfortunately or I would be using Typescript completely

Comment: Try `className = null` like you did for the width or do it via defaultPropTypes

Comment: VSCode is doing Typescript intellisense on your JS code (it does this by default). Just ignore it or turn it off. Or better yet listen to it, and write your code in a more statically-analyzable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested I set default values in the prop parameters. I also added the types in JSDoc which seems to help

```js
// CreditCard.jsx
/*
 * @param {Object} props
 * @param {boolean} [props.active = false]
 * @param {string} [props.className = '']
 * @param {boolean} [props.png = false]
 * @param {number} [props.width = 100]
 */
const CreditCard = ({ active = false, className = '', png = false, width = 100, ...props })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { FC } from 'react';

...

interface CreditCardProps {
    active: boolean;
    className?: string;
    png: boolean;
    width: number
}

const CreditCard: FC<CreditCardProps> = ({ active, className, png, width = 100, ...props }) => {
    ...
};
```

With defaultProps:

```
CreditCard.defaultProps = {
  className: null, // or ''
}
```